# C-x 8 " a missing

Tags: unicode, emacs

In older Emacs versions `C-x 8 " a` used to insert `ä` (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS). Now, there is only `C-x 8 RET` to insert a Unicode character. 
`C-x 8 C-h` tells me that there is only this single binding to `ucs-insert` with prefix `C-x 8`.

Is there a mode to get the olde combinations, too?

I am running 23.3.1 and have no choice to upgrade.

Comment: I get a whole bunch of stuff that comes up with `C-x 8 C-h` on the snapshot developer build 25.1.50.1 running `Emacs -Q`.  What version of Emacs and OS are you using?  The stable release of 24.5.1 on OSX also works out of the box as it should.  Try running with `Emacs -Q` to see if your user configuration has changed something.

Comment: @lawlist: I run there a default installed 23.3.1

Comment: Ah . . . I don't have access at the moment to the old/outdated version of Emacs.  Perhaps someone else can help -- the only thing I can suggest is `Emacs -Q` to see if it works by default, or upgrade to a current version of Emacs.

Comment: Thank you! You are right with -Q, seems there are some site defaults I have to go through!

Comment: Try `emacs -q` instead of `emacs -Q`, to see if the problem comes from your init file or the site-file. Depending on which it is, recursively bisect that file, commenting out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8,... until you find the cause.

Comment: @Drew: Tx.  I did this. It had something to do with desktop as well, ugh...

Comment: If you think the answer might be interesting to others, please post it (and accept it). If not, consider perhaps deleting the question.

Comment: @Drew: Yup - it's really odd that `C-x 8 RET` still worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the problem, I first `C-x r t ;xyx;`ed about half of the `.emacs.el`. It soon boiled down to an old library that happened to have:

```
(setq key-translation-map)
```

whose value was originally

```
(24 keymap
    (56 . iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map)))
```

`24` is also known as `^X` and `56` as `?8`.

What I still do not understand about this is this: After `C-x C-e`ing `(setq key-tranlation-map)` all the `C-x 8` combinations are undefined **except** `C-x 8 RET`. (Warning: don't try it with your working, loaded Emacs, take a fresh `-q`ed one).